# kernel headers and kernel devel

Tags: centos, kernel

command

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel
```

output

```
kernel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64

kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64

kernel-headers-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64

kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64

kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
```

command

uname -r

output

```
3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
```

trying to install matching devel:

sudo yum install http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

I get:

```
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/rt-tester/rt-tester.pyo from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/sortextable from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/sortextable.c from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/sortextable.h from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/tags.sh from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/tracing/draw_functrace.pyc from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/tracing/draw_functrace.pyo from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/unifdef from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.feature from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.include from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/scripts/Makefile.include from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/objtool/objtool from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/perf/Makefile.perf from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/tools/scripts/Makefile.arch from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux.id from install of kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
```

---

This is our production server. How do I safely resolve this?

If I run

sudo yum install kernel-headers

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

 * base: centos.excellmedia.net

 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net

 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net

Package kernel-headers-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Nothing to do
```

sudo yum install kernel-devel

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

 * base: centos.excellmedia.net

 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net

 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net

Package kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Nothing to do

Comment: You can try this: yum install “kernel-headers-uname-r == $(uname -r)”. I believe it should work if there is a matching package in the repository.

Comment: What do yo do if there isn't one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Kernel devels run:

`yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64` OR `yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`

To install Kernel headers run:

`yum install kernel-headers-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64` OR `yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)`