# Cannot install any specifc version of `kernel-headers` on Fedora

Tags: fedora, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, version

my goal is to make my kernel-headers to have the same version as my kernel and kernel-devel. Currently I have:

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-headers
Last metadata expiration check: 1:55:19 ago ...
Package kernel-headers-5.15.4-200.fc35.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

$ yum --showduplicate list kernel-headers
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:37 ago ...
Installed Packages
kernel-headers.x86_64                          5.15.4-200.fc35                           @updates
Available Packages
kernel-headers.i686                            5.14.9-300.fc35                           fedora  
kernel-headers.x86_64                          5.14.9-300.fc35                           fedora  
kernel-headers.x86_64                          5.15.4-200.fc35                           updates 

$ uname -a
Linux fedora 5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
```

I want to have kernel-headers set to `5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64`.
I have tried everything from

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045451/linux-kernel-header-files-to-match-the-current-kernel

[2] [yum installs kernel-devel different from my kernel version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/yum-installs-kernel-devel-different-from-my-kernel-version)

[3] [kernel headers and kernel devel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461493/kernel-headers-and-kernel-devel)

My problem is that I am able to install kernel-headers that are only in the available packages list.

What I tried (and failed) was:

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-headers-generic
Last metadata expiration check: 1:59:50 ago ...
No match for argument: kernel-headers-generic
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-headers-generic

$ sudo yum install kernel-headers-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 2:00:09 ago ...
No match for argument: kernel-headers-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-headers-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64

$ sudo yum install kernel-headers-generic-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 2:00:15 ago ...
No match for argument: kernel-headers-generic-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-headers-generic-5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64
```

So question is how to install kernel-header `5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64`. And since the "usual" methods did not help, I am not sure if it is relevant/equivalent to ask, how to expand the list of `Available Packages` which appears with `--showduplicates`.

Comment: `kernel-headers` is the user space headers . I.e. `/usr/include/{asm/, asm-generic/, drm/, linux/,,, ,,,`, and the version does not follow the kernel version. Older Fedora versions (and other older OS) did not / did never update `kernel-headers`. ........... "kernel-headers-generic" is one of the Debian/Ubuntu nick names for kernel-devel → /usr/src/[kernel].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an [answer to a similar question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/where-to-get-kernel-headers-5-15-11-200-fc35-x86-64/19396), this package isn't released with every version.
Yum doesn't omit any packages here. I'd recommend just trying the devel, as recommended in the first linked forum.